# Active Storage migration arising error on upgrading to rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

When I have upgraded my rails 5 to rails 6 and we are using active storage in our application. For active storage, it adds a new migration in rails 6. While running this migration I am facing following issue for some of the existing records

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "active_storage_attachments" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_c3b3935057"
DETAIL:  Key (blob_id)=(256) is not present in table "active_storage_blobs".
```

Is there any way to fix this without deleting records from `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs`?

Comment: I also have this problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: yes I have added optional: true in models with foreign key  this only solved my prob no other fixes work for me

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but if somebody has the same issue, I found this solution :

```
ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(blob_id: x).destroy_all
```

Run it in your rails console. Replace x with the ID specified in the failed migration until there are no more invalid data, and the migration passes.
Link to the github comment : https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33405#issuecomment-421575934